# How to override entity.name.function using regex?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Syntax my functions: `return_type func_name(parameters)`

I need to get only `func_name`. I used regex

`'(?:(String|Array|Map|Bool|bool|exception|string|Int|Float|Variant|Object|Message|message|void))\s({{identifier}}(?=\s*\())'` but i get back `return_type + func_name`. If i used `?!` i get a function call.

`func_name(arg)`, example: `ToString("")`.

`{{identifier}} = \b[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\b`

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
(?:String|Array|Map|Bool|bool|exception|string|Int|Float|Variant|Object|Message|message|void)\s+\K[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*(?=\s*\()
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/IH3XK3/1).

The `(?:String|Array|Map|Bool|bool|exception|string|Int|Float|Variant|Object|Message|message|void)` matches types, `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters, `\K` will omit the matched text, `[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*` will match a function name if there are any whitespaces + `(` following it.

Comment: in Sumbline it regex not work :( my cfg for name function `  - match: '(?:String|Array|Map|Bool|bool|exception|string|Int|Float|Variant|Object|Message|message|void)\s+\K[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*(?=\s*\() `
      scope: entity.name.function`